# How to construct url in swift 3/4 using URL(string: , relativeTo:)

Tags: swift3, swift4

I'm trying to construct a url in swift 3 but I don't understand why it doesn't append the string to the baseURL properly the output is not what I expected. In swift 2 it worked fine.

```
let token = "12token34"

let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.mysite.net/map/\(token)/")

let desiredURL = URL(string: "37.8267,-122.4233", relativeTo: baseURL as URL?)
```

result

```
37.8267,-122.4233 -- https://api.mysite.net/map/12token34/
```

I was expecting the following:

```
https://api.mysite.net/map/12token34/37.8267,-122.4233
```

Comment: Your method it is working it just doesn't print as you expect

Comment: try `print(desiredURL?.absoluteString)`

Comment: Note: No need to cast your URL to URL?

Comment: Ok thanks for the alternative way to append it. But now that I know it works I don't know why I don't get the json response that i expect.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: feel free to edit your question and post what you expect and what you are getting. Does it work appending the components to the URL ?

Comment: yes it does thank you. However the variables are still in the same scope of the optional binding block which I'm trying to avoid that so I can use it outside. But the appendingPathComponent is something new I didn't know so it's all good.

Answer (score 3):

The initializer is doing what you think it ought to; it's the string representation of `URL` that's confusing. In the REPL:

```
1> import Foundation
2> let token = "12token34"
token: String = "12token34"
3> let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.mysite.net/map/\(token)/")
baseURL: URL? = "https://api.mysite.net/map/12token34/"
```

So far so good; now comes the confusing part:

```
4> let desiredURL = URL(string: "37.8267,-122.4233", relativeTo: baseURL as URL?)
desiredURL: URL? = "37.8267,-122.4233 -- ttps://api.mysite.net/map/12token34/"
```

This is a relative URL object, but it does actually represent the URL you expect it to:

```
5> desiredURL!.absoluteString
$R0: String = "https://api.mysite.net/map/12token34/37.8267,-122.4233"
```

If you want it in absolute form, you can get it with `absoluteURL`:

```
6> desiredURL!.absoluteURL
$R1: URL = "https://api.mysite.net/map/12token34/37.8267,-122.4233"
```

Note that this works for more  cases as well:

```
1> import Foundation
2> let base = URL(string: "http://example.org/foo/bar/baz.txt")
base: URL? = "http://example.org/foo/bar/baz.txt"
```

Siblings in the same directory:

```
3> let sib = URL(string: "./qux.txt", relativeTo: base!)
sib: URL? = "./qux.txt -- ttp://example.org/foo/bar/baz.txt"
4> sib!.absoluteURL
$R0: URL = "http://example.org/foo/bar/qux.txt"
```

Up the directory tree and back down:

```
5> let cousin = URL(string: "../corge/garply.txt", relativeTo: base!)
cousin: URL? = "../corge/garply.txt -- ttp://example.org/foo/bar/baz.txt"
6> cousin!.absoluteURL 
$R1: URL = "http://example.org/foo/corge/garply.txt"
```

All the way to the root and back down:

```
7> let fromRoot = URL(string: "/waldo/fred.txt", relativeTo: base!)
fromRoot: URL? = "/waldo/fred.txt -- ttp://example.org/foo/bar/baz.txt"
8> fromRoot!.absoluteURL
$R2: URL = "http://example.org/waldo/fred.txt"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let token = "12token34"
let baseURL = URL(string: "https://api.mysite.net/map/\(token)/")
let desiredURL = URL(string: "37.8267,-122.4233", relativeTo: baseURL as URL?)
```

This is the reason of error:

```
/// Initialize with string, relative to another URL.
///
/// Returns `nil` if a `URL` cannot be formed with the string (for example, if the string contains characters that are illegal in a URL, or is an empty string).
public init?(string: String, relativeTo url: URL?)
```

So if you want to append url, the output should be like:

```
let output = URL(string: baseURL!.absoluteString)
output?.appendingPathComponent("37.8267,-122.4233")
```

so you can directly use:

```
baseURL!.appendingPathComponent("37.8267,-122.4233")
```

Comment: that I have used with playground for print, the actual answer is last line.